# EXT JS: is it possible to add url to reader and writer in proxy

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, extjs

I am creating a simple project that uses Spring 3, EXTJS 4, hibernate 3 and i want to create an ext form that pulls data from a database and you can add, remove and update this information. I have the form bring populated and now i am trying to figure out how to update a customer in the form.

What is the best way to do this? what i was thinking of doing is using a different url for the writer than the reader so that it can pass a customer object back to my java classes to update the database

This is the way i currently have the form being populated

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Person',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web',
        reader: {
            type: 'json' 
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
.....
```

and i was wondering would it be possible to use different urls for the reader and writer like so

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Person',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web/update'
        }
    },
......
```

these are the methods that i am using to populate the form and update the customer

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/web")  
public class Web {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    List<Customer> list = customerService.returnAllCustomers();
    return list;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void updateCustomers(Customer customer) {
    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
}
......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have separate URLs, you can switch to using `AjaxProxy`. Readers and Writers should not be configured with URLs because they just are just decoders and encoders. Here is an example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Person',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create  : 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web/create',
            read    : 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web',
            update  : 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web/update',
            destroy : 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/service/web/delete'
        }
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, if you want to continue using a restful implementation, then you will need to change your server side API to map the create, read, update and destroy methods to `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` respectively. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody void updateCustomers(Customer customer) {
    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
}
```